# No Activity found to handle Intent: intent.action.PICK

Tags: android, audio, filepicker

How can I solve this error on android 9.0. When I run on android 7 and below there is no error

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.PICK dat=content://media/external/audio/media }
```

Here is the method

```
private void pickAudio() {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(i, PICK_AUDIO_REQUEST);
    }
```

Comment: Remove the second parameter at creating your intent. And set a mime type.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a try catch to catch the exception and display a  Alert Dialog?
**Note: i changed your method name

```
private void pickAudioIntent() {
try{
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(i, PICK_AUDIO_REQUEST);
}catch(Exception e){
//No activity? Display alert Dialog to user
    }
```

You can also check before hand if any activity can handle the intent by doing the below

```
public static boolean isIntentAvailable(Intent intent) {
    final PackageManager mgr = mContext.getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> list =
        mgr.queryIntentActivities(intent,
            PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    return list.size() > 0;
}
```

That would change the pickAudioIntent() to :

```
private void pickAudioIntent() {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        if(isIntentAvailable(i)){
           startActivityForResult(i, PICK_AUDIO_REQUEST);
        return;
        }
     //Show Dialog to user as no intent available
    }
```

Comment: I have tried and error exception is no intent activity available, how can I workout that to get it working

Comment: Whats the value of `PICK_AUDIO_REQUEST` ?

Comment: 159, when I change MediaStore.Audio.Media to something like MediaStore.Images.Media the app don't crash

Answer (score 1):

For anyone facing this issue on Android API level 30 or above, one of the possible reasons could be [Android Package Visibility](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/package-visibility-in-android-11-cc857f221cd9) changes.

You need to add

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

to your `Manifest.xml` file

> If the issue persists, it means there is no app to handle that request. You will have to go with `try-catch` then.